# Vaadin-on-Kotlin: Fill grid with data

Tags: kotlin, vaadin

Maybe I missed the specific section in documentation ([grids](http://www.vaadinonkotlin.eu/grids.html)), but how can I add simple data to a grid (without database connection)?

```
data class Person(val fname: String, val lname: String, val age: Int)

class MainView : VerticalLayout() {
    init {
        val d = listOf(
            Person("A", "B", 123),
            Person("C", "D", 456),
            Person("E", "F", 789)
        )
        // data not shown:
        grid(dataProvider = ListDataProvider(d)) {
            addColumnFor(Person::fname)
            addColumnFor(Person::lname)
            addColumnFor(Person::age)
        }
       // data not shown:
        grid<Person> {
            setItems(d)
            addColumnFor(Person::fname)
            addColumnFor(Person::lname)
            addColumnFor(Person::age)
        }
        // data not shown:
        val grid = Grid<Person>().apply {
            setItems(d)
            addColumn(Person::fname)
            addColumn(Person::lname)
            addColumn(Person::age)
        }
        add(grid)
    }
}
```

For this example I used the starter from [here](https://github.com/mvysny/karibu10-helloworld-application). Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is simply to display a Grid as demonstrated in the [official vaadin 10 docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid.html).

What I am missing here??

Kind regards.

EDIT:

Disabling the "height" property of the table (#table.vaadin-grid) fixes the error. Is this a bug in the karibu-dsl?

Comment: Which version of Vaadin 10 are you using? It could have been a bug in 10.0.2; I added your code into the newest `karibu10-helloworld-application` which uses 10.0.4 and it works - the grid is displayed for me, without using `isHeightByRows`.

If that doesn't help, please try adding `@BodySize(width = "100vw", height = "100vh")` and `@Viewport("width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes")` to your `MainView`

Comment: This shouldn't be a bug in `karibu-dsl` since it's just a thin wrapper over Vaadin 10, so I'd attribute the bug to the Vaadin itself. Please try Vaadin 10.0.4 and let me know if the issue is fixed for you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `isHeightByRows = true` solves it for now:

```
grid(dataProvider = ListDataProvider(d)) {
    isHeightByRows = true
    addColumnFor(Person::fname)
    addColumnFor(Person::lname)
    addColumnFor(Person::age)
}
```